# While loop showing no output in python

Tags: python, algorithm, while-loop

I decided to start solving the problems on project euler and i am pretty much stuck on this first one.
When i run this while loop in powershell or using visual studio code, it shows nothing. Powershell just shows a blinking cursor and visual returns the file path.

The question is: 
If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

```
total = 0
x = 1
a = 3*x
b = 5*x

while (a or b<1000):
    total = total + a + b
    x =+ 1

print total
```

I also tried changing the code a bit, but didnt work

```
total = 0
x = 1
a = 3*x
b = 5*x

while (a<1000):
    total = total + a 
    x =+ 1

while(b<1000):
    total =+ b
    x=+1

print total
```

Comment: Indentation matters in Python. If you're going to post Python code, please make an effort to reproduce your indentation accurately. If readers have to try and guess your actual indentation, they may miss problems or introduce new ones into the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the indentation errors are due to copy-paste errors, you have an infinite loop. `while a < 1000` but you never change `a` inside.

Since you know the range of iteration it makes more sense to use a `for` loop:

```
print(sum(n for n in range(1, 10) if n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0))
# 23
print(sum(n for n in range(1, 100) if n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0))
# 2318
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the problem simple to yourself. at first, find your variables and constants. 
your variables are the number that changes from 1 to 1000 and the total sum.

try this :

```
total = 0 
i = 1 # your counter 
while (i < 1000) :
    if i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0 : 
        total = total + i
    i +=1 
print total
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the infinite loop, so here is my solution:

```
def findAndSum(x):
    total = 0
    for i in range(x):
        if(i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0):
            total +=i

    print total


findAndSum(10)
findAndSum(100)
findAndSum(1000)
```

I think this solution is easier to understand. First you call the method with an range you want. Then you check each numer if it is divisible by 3 or 5 without rest and add it to total.